# Reference for Hypergraph Expander Mixing Lemma Generalization

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Wikipedia lists a [hypergraph generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_mixing_lemma#Generalization_to_hypergraphs) of the expander mixing lemma as follows.

Let $H$ be a $k$-uniform hypergraph, i.e. a hypergraph in which every "edge" is a tuple of $k$ vertices. For any choice of subsets $V_1,\ldots,V_k$ of vertices, $$\left||e(V_1,\ldots,V_k)| - \frac{k!|E(H)|}{n^k}|V_1|\cdots|V_k|\right| \le \lambda_2(H)\sqrt{|V_1|\cdots|V_k|}.$$

However, the [reference](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Eavi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/FW95/fw95a.pdf) listed for it by Friedman and Widgerson doesn't appear to (at least explicitly) state such a theorem. Is there a different reference someone could suggest, or explanation of how Friedman's paper does show such a theorem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some background on the mixing lemma in hypergraph settings, you should have a look at [Inverse Expander Mixing for Hypergraphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2285), section 3, by Cohen et al. It includes some interesting points (e.g. the eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ does not correspond to any matrix).

Then, [Eigenvalues and linear quasirandom hypergraphs](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/forum-of-mathematics-sigma/article/eigenvalues-and-linear-quasirandom-hypergraphs/9F869EBF61188CBAB9B8D7272559CC28) includes a proof of the statement.